# [Byte[]] to [System.Drawing.Image] to [Byte[]] with Powershell Azure Function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, converters, memorystream

I am trying to get an get an image file from blob storage, reduce the dimensions of the image and save the result to blob storage using a PowerShell Azure Function

```
$i_ms = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$InputBlob)
$i_image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($i_ms)

[int32]$new_width = $i_image.Width
[int32]$new_height = $i_image.Height
[System.Drawing.Image]$o_image = $i_image.GetThumbnailImage($new_width, $new_height, $null, [intptr]::Zero);

$o_ms = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream
$o_image.Save($o_ms, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::JPEG)
$OutputBlob = $o_ms.ToArray

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $OutputBlob
```

When I reduced my code to the following (ommiting the image resize code) the issue remains, so the issue seems to stem from my attempt to go from the original byte array to an image and back

```
$i_ms = new-object System.IO.MemoryStream(,$InputBlob)
$i_image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($i_ms)
$OutputBlob = $i_ms.ToArray

Push-OutputBinding -Name outputBlob -Value $OutputBlob
```

I have come to the above code after finding similar posts for VBScript and C# but I am struggling with getting the same working in PowerShell.

Comment: You can refer to [ConvertTo-Base64-BitmapImage-Long](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AnyBox/0.2/Content/HelperFunctions.ps1), [ConvertTo-Bytes.ps1](https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/ConvertTo-Bytes.ps1) and [ConvertFrom-Bytes.ps1](https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/ConvertFrom-Bytes.ps1)

Answer (score 0):

this should be used like this -> $OutputBlob = $o_ms.ToArray()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).